# How to return p0 database snapshot

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How can I return `p0` in fun `getItemCount()` ?
I am new to kotlin, I guess thats why I don't know this

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {


        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("proizvodi/Kalendari")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                Log.d("p0",p0.childrenCount.toString())


            }

        })
        return p0 //i want count to return here
    }
```

Comment: What you want exactly ?

Comment: I want to search how many things i have in database, and to return it to getItemCount() so i can display that many items in recylcer view

Comment: You already have `p0.child()`

Comment: i cant use it as return on bottom of code, unresolved reference problem

Comment: Posted answer try this way

Comment: There is no way you can return that count as a result of a method. Please check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** answer and the duplicates to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        var count = 0 // init count variable 

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("proizvodi/Kalendari")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("p0",p0.childrenCount.toString())
                count = p0.childrenCount
            }

        })
        return count  //return count 
    }
```

Comment: When i return count on end is 0, when i return insine fun onDataChange its 4 like it should be on bottom

Comment: Ok so return onDataChange(..). it should be ok